# how to make multiple handlers for one Get-request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

I have such view for search query

```
@model MvcA. Models.SellsLiveSearch@using ( Html.BeginForm ("Search", "Search",FormMethod .Get)) {
    @Html. ValidationSummary(true )

    <fieldset>
        <legend> Введите данные </legend>


        <select id="HowManyRoom" name= "HowManyRoom" ><option></ option>
        <option value="1" >1</ option>
        <option value="2" >2</ option>
        <option value="3" >3</ option>
        <option value="4" >4</ option>
        <option value="5" >4</ option>
        </select>

        <select id="TimeRange" name= "TimeRange" ><option></ option>
        <option> 1 </option >
        <option> 2 </option >
        <option> 3 </option >
        <option> 4 </option >
        </select>

        @Html. TextBox ("expencefrom")
        @Html. TextBox ("expenceto")

          <p>
            <input type="submit" value= "Search" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchPost(SellsLiveSearch Per)
{         string query = "SELECT * FROM SellsLives WHERE SellsLiveID!=0"
          if (Per .HowManyRoom !=null )
             { query = query + " AND HowManyRoom=" + Per.HowManyRoom ; 
                       }

          if (Per .TimeRange != "" )
             { query =query + " AND TimeRange=" + Per.TimeRange ;
                       }

          if (Per .ExpenceFrom != null )

             { query = query + " AND Expence<=" + Per.ExpenceFrom ; }

          int newcost ;
          if (Per .ExpenceTo != null )

             {
              newcost = (int)( 0.1 * Per. ExpenceTo + Per. ExpenceTo);
              query = query + " AND Expence>=" + newcost;
                    }
}
```

I want to save result of search in cache and make pagination for page through.

Question:

How best to make handling page turning?

Make extra action for the treatment of Get-query pages transmitted? Or give pagination another controller, and will be separate search page and separately with the results, which will be handled by another controller and have another address and take from the cache results? Or make one common action that will choose the processing depending on the specified page?

The final page should contain the parameters Get-request and page number, how to get there?

Comment: I think you have bigger issues here, like how are you negating an SQL injection attack?

Comment: @Ashley Medway , : D Yes, it also if it possible